# How to insert a new heading from a collapsed heading?

Tags: org-mode

Here, two headings are collapsed, but they do have some content represented by org's s`...`

```
* Heading 1...
* Heading 2...
```

How can I insert a heading right below `Heading 2`, including below all its content? My cursor is at caret when I do `M-RET`: `Heading 2^...`. As example:

```
* Heading 1...
* Heading 2...
* Heading 3...
```

Right now, it seems the behaviour is kind of buggy, where pressing `M-RET` on the previous heading's `...` will lead move all the content below the heading? Unfortunately this isn't the behaviour that I want..

```
* Heading 1...
* Heading 2
* ...
```

Comment: Go to after the ellipsis with `C-n` or `<right>...<right>`  (as many as required to move you to after the ellipsis - you can use `C-f` instead of `<right>` if you prefer) - and *then* press `M-RET`.

Comment: @NickD Hmm, this inserts a second level heading: `** ` instead of what I would like: `* `. Any way to change to same level heading behaviour?

Comment: So you have a second level heading under `Heading 2`? What I do is insert a heading and then adjust the level with `M-<left>` or `M-<right>`, although there are probably slicker methods: my trouble is that the only way I can remember these things is if they are baked into my muscle memory and that's `M-RET` and `M-<left>` - anything else might as well not exist :-) But try `C-u M-RET`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for `C-u M-RET` which calls `org-insert-heading` with a prefix argument. The doc string for `org-insert-heading` says:

> With a ‘C-u’ prefix, set ‘org-insert-heading-respect-content’ to
> a non-nil value for the duration of the command.  This forces the
> insertion of a heading after the current subtree, independently
> on the location of point.

So if you are in the first-level subtree, it will go to the end of the subtree and insert a first-level heading, but if you are in a second-level subtree, it will go to the end of that and insert a second-level heading. In this second case, there is no way to guess that you want a first level heading, so you'll have to adjust the level with `M-<left>` or `M-<right>` as I mentioned in the comment.

If you really want a first-level heading at the end of the current subtree, you can define a function and bind it to a key (but IMO, that's a waste):

```el
(defun ndk/org-insert-top-level-heading-at-end-of-current-subtree ()
   (interactive)
   (org-insert-heading '(4) nil t))

(define-key 'org-mode-map (kbd "S-<f12>") #'ndk/org-insert-top-level-heading-at-end-of-current-subtree)
```

The `'(4)` makes `org-insert-heading` behave the same way that it would if it were called interactively with a `C-u` prefix and the `t` forces it to insert a first-level headline instead of what it normally would. I bound it to `S-<f12>` because that is likely unused but you can suit yourself.

Comment: No ya, `C-u M-RET` works fine. I just did an example for first level headings but this default behaviour is exactly what I needed. Thanks! I saw using `C-h k M-RET` that this keybinding should do `org-insert-heading` in the correct conditions, but didn't really understand the lisp code. Now it seems that doing `RET` on the link to `org-insert-heading` does mention this lol.. Does your knowledge about org-mode come from reading the manual from start to end, reading the source code or doing such experiments? (my guess is experiments, but..)

Comment: All three - but my first encounter with Org mode was ca 2006, so I've had plenty of time to do them :-)

Comment: Just a curiously : why not type star with a single stroke instead of C-u M-Return:-)

Comment: Note where `point` is: at the end of the headline but before the ellipsis that rrepresents the folded content. If you type `*` there, it would break the current headline.